# create a new list of dictionaries based on a key in one list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary, sum

I'm pretty new to the python programing.
I would like to create a new list of dictionaries based key `name`. if `name` is equal sum the `id` value.

```
a = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'paul'},{'id': 2, 'name': 'john'},{'id': 3, 'name': 'john'},{'id': 4, 'name': 'john'}]
```

New list would be like:

```
new_a = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'paul'},{'id': 9, 'name': 'john'}]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will also do what you're asking, however, I think a different setup of data structures might be able to do it better.

```
new_a = list()
names_list = list()
for el in a:
    if el['name'] not in names_list:
        new_a.append({'name':el['name'],'id':el['id']})
        names_list.append(el['name'])
    else:
        for new_el in new_a:
            if el['name'] == new_el['name']:
                new_el['id'] += el['id']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Counter` for that and then do some conversions, like:

```
from collections import Counter

ctr = Counter()
for dic in a:
    ctr[dic['name']] += dic['id']
new_a = [{'name': name, 'id': id} for name,id in ctr.iteritems()]
```

This yields:

```
>>> new_a
[{'name': 'paul', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'john', 'id': 9}]
```

Note that the **order of the list is undetermined**.